# Is it acceptable to transform data for use in a GLM using Poisson?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, regression-strategies

I have transformed my explanatory variables to a normal distribution as these variables include, proportions (logit transformed) and non normally distributed data (various transformations).  The dependent variable is a count, hence I am using "family = poisson".  I have read in some sources that it is uneccessary to transform the explanatory data but I don't understand the reasoning behind this.

Was transforming this data incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression models condition on the right-hand-side (predictor) variables and make some sort of distribution assumption for the response variable conditional on all the $X$s.  What matters for $X$ is the shape of its effect on $Y$, hence the popularity of regression splines.  The only time I worry about the marginal distribution of an $X$ is when it is extremely skewed, because on the average such $X$s predict $Y$ better if they are "straightened out" a bit.  I often fit a restricted cubic spline in the cube root of such an $X$.

So the short answer is that transforming the $X$s for the reasons you provided is not correct.  And be sure to worry a bit more about the Poisson distributional assumption.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I'm afraid your response went largely over my head.  I carried out the transformations/analysis on the advice of someone else but this appears to be incorrect.  I have only been introduced to GLMs in the last two months so my knowledge is VERY limited, could you recommend any basic texts/sources?

Comment: There are so many resources for linear models that it's hard to know where to begin.  I hope that others will respond with book recommendations.